# variable in script tag in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularJS application, and I need (for a service provider) to include this piece of code in one of my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ptag_params = {
        zone: "listing",
        customerId: {{user.uuid}},
        siteType: "d",
};
</script>
```

I need to pass the user.uuid dynamically to that variable, what is the best/cleanest way to do this ?

thanks

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive ...

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `directive` whose role would be to craft the fragment of html given a specific uuid.
You can find AngularJS's directive tutorial [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).